# What is the difference between DbEntityEntry and Changetracker in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

As they both can track current and original value, track states of an entity?

Answer (score 2):

The change tracker uses the Entity Entries to track the changes.  Each Entry has a reference to the Entity, along with it's change state and the original values of its properties.